# Autohotkey script to remap Shfit+Capslock+I doesn't work, but does for other letters

Tags: autohotkey

I had a script written to remap ijkl to the arrow keys when holding capslock and shift, and it works for everything but the i key. I'm thoroughly confused. Here's a simplified version of the script, and in it, the remaps to u and o work, but not the one to i. Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
#Requires AutoHotkey >=2.0

#HotIf GetKeyState("Shift")
Capslock & i::Send "{Up}"
Capslock & u::Send "{Up}"
Capslock & o::Send "{Down}"
#HotIf
```

I expected it to work and send the up arrow key. I stopped running all other scripts and reduced this script down to a single command and then compared it with other similar single commands.

Comment: Works here. Maybe your keyboard needs cleaning.

Comment: hmm. Yeah it works with plain capslock+i, and ctrl+capslock+i, but not shift+capslock+i. But good to know it works on your end. Must be something random interfering here.